# What is PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I read a lot of articles about `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, I understood what does it do, however, I am unable to understand how does it do that? How a macro can be used to initialize a variable just by assigning its name to that variable?

What I know about macros is that they can be used just as functions, such as:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Now we can use this macro as a function like `Max(a, b)`.

But how can we write a macro that can be used in the way which `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is used like:

```
int x = Macro_Name;
```

Then `x` will be initialized to a specific value (like when a mutex is initialized once `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is assigned to it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a snippet from the source code of libpthread, taken from http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/hurd/libpthread.git/tree/sysdeps/pthread/bits/types/struct___pthread_mutex.h (I only removed comments that are irrelevant to the question)

```
/* User visible part of a mutex.  */
struct __pthread_mutex
{
  __pthread_spinlock_t __held;
  __pthread_spinlock_t __lock;
  char *__cthreadscompat1;
  struct __pthread *__queue;
  struct __pthread_mutexattr *__attr;
  void *__data;
  void *__owner;
  unsigned __locks;
};

#  define __PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER \
    { __PTHREAD_SPIN_LOCK_INITIALIZER, __PTHREAD_SPIN_LOCK_INITIALIZER, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

From that, it can be seen that the macro hides an initializer list for the structure that represents the "user visible part of a mutex". Most members of the struct (including pointers) are set to 0, and  internal spin locks are initialized with their own initializer macro, which is probably defined similarly.

Of course it's just one implementation, but I guess other implementations might have something similar.